# When refresh page request url id parameter missing

Tags: vuejs2

I have vue 2 project and set everything dynamicly problem is when visit a specific page i can see id as parameter in request url but when reload page it missing id get it from prop and vuex store i ve already checked it still stored vuex even page reloaded and correctly send as prop

I've tried to debug like this in my service
`import { serviceBase } from "../../service";

```
export default {
  ...serviceBase,
  preList: function(params) {
    console.log(params);
    let id = params.project_id || "-";
    console.log("id", id);
    delete params.project_id;
    return `projects/${id}`;
  },
  preListOption: {
    getList: true,
    get: true,
    create: true,
    update: true,
    delete: true,
    deleteList: true
  }
};`
```

in console it gives "-" weird thing is i have another page with different name but same architecture it works please help me out